# What do we need that $A \lhd B$ (for $A,B \subset G$)

Tags: abstract-algebra, normal-subgroups

Let $G$ be a group and $A,B$ be normal subgroups s.t. $A \subset B$. I wanna show that $A \lhd B$. Is this enough to use that $A \lhd G$? Because this is equivalent to say $\forall g \in G$, $gAg^{-1} \subset A$, so it also should be right that $\forall h \in B (\subset G)$, $hAh^{-1} \subset A$. Hence $A \lhd B$. Is this right?

Comment: It is sufficient, but not necessary, to show that $A$ is also normal in $G$.  They are NOT equivalent.

Comment: Yes, I know that it is not equivalent! But nice that it is enough